# Can I translate this problem from $L_2(\Omega)$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, isometry

I would like to ask whether or not, my reasoning is correct.

This is probably a dumb question, but I haven't done any functional analysis course, and am kind of worried if the following reasoning (which seems to me as intuitive) is all right.

I am trying to solve a problem about some particular set of random variables $\ \mathcal{S}, \ $ 
 $$\mathcal{S}\subset L_{2}(\Omega):= \{X: \mathbb{E}X^{2}<\infty\}.$$
I have proved that $S$ is a subset of
$$\hat{\mathcal{S}}=\{X\in L_{2}(\Omega): \mathbb{E}|X-X_{0}|^{2}=1\},$$
for some r.v. $\ X_{0}\in L_2(\Omega). \ $
I want to find a bound/calculate 
$$\sup_{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{i,j}\mathbb{E}|X_i-X_j|^2.$$
And now, what i would like to say is:

$X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \ $ are $\ n \ $ points in Hilbert space $\ L_{2}(\Omega), \ $ so they must lie on some $\ n-1 \ $ dimensional subspace $\ H \ $. This subspace is (I believe) isometric to the space $\ \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \ $. Let $\ x_{1},\cdots, x_{n} \ $ be corresponding set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Then $\ x_1,\cdots, x_n$ still lies on some sphere $\hat{\mathcal{S}}'$ with radius $1$. Finally
$$\sum_{i,j}\mathbb{E}|X_i-X_j|^2=\sum_{i,j}||x_i-x_j||^2,$$
so 
$$\sup_{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{i,j}\mathbb{E}|X_i-X_j|^2\le
\sup_{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n \in \hat{\mathcal{S}}'}\sum_{i,j}||x_i-x_j||^2$$
which is now an euclidean geometry problem (already solved).

Is this reasoning correct? I will be glad for any help.

Comment: To be clear, for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$  you want to bound $\sup_{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{i,j}\mathbb{E}|X_i-X_j|^2$, yes?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: You could give a crude estimate as $$\sup_{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{i,j}\mathbb{E}|X_i-X_j|^2 = \sup_{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{i,j}\Vert X_i - X_0 -(X_j - X_0) \Vert^2 \leq  \sup_{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{i,j}\Vert X_i  - X_0 \Vert^2 + 2 \Vert X_i - X_0 \Vert  \Vert X_j - X_0\Vert + \Vert X_j - X_0 \Vert^2 \leq 4 n(n-1) $$

Comment: This paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.02745.pdf solves geometric problem I mentioned. It follows, if my reasoning is correct, that $n^2$ is a bound. In my original problem, I know examples, that give me exactly $n^2$.

Comment: The argument looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Why must $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ lie in an $n-1$-dimensional subspace? If they are linearly independent, the subspace they span is $n$-dimensional.

Comment: I am talking about affine subspace and its dimension.